# text editor: change font in replace dialog

Tags: editor

Is there a text editor that allows to change the font of it's dialogs?

I'd like to have the dialogs with the same font as the source code.

In windows, I managed to get bigger fonts and change fonts for all menus etc, but the dialog fonts in Crimson are still the same. Would I really have to compile Crimson or Scite etc myself to get FixedSys in their replace dialogs? Is there no tricky way to force dialogs use a certain font? Not just setting 120 DPI in windows...

Thanks a lot

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, this value makes Scite use Fixedsys in dialogs

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Fixedsys"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always use an editor like Vim which doesn't use dialogs.

Comment: Likewise, emacs. The minibuffer is exactly as configurable as all other buffers...

Answer (score 0):

with the "window color" font settings and fontsubstitutes registry values set to Fixedsys *and* restarting, finally Scite uses it in its dialogs :)
Though Crimson and ConTEXT don't